# Strange behavior with Windows 7 gaming PC - RAM, HDD, or other issue?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, motherboard

## With Graphics Card Installed

Boot up machine, takes 5 minutes or so from post to login, then takes another 5 minutes from login to fully loaded desktop.

After about 1 hour to 4 hours of general usage, entire screen becomes flickering, fuzzy, snow-like pixels, frozen. Sound glitches with an 8-bit explosion sound, then stutters indefinitely from there on .

Keyboard and mouse are dead. Hard boot is required.

## Without Graphics Card Installed

Software begin gradually freezing up and auto-terminate, including Explorer.exe

The only software remaining open are NotePad++ and FireFox

Desktop is blank of icons

Ctrl+Alt+Del does nothing

No Task mgr (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), no access to Run.(Win+R)

FireFox does not allow downloading of any files. When scrolling through text, there are giant black rectangles that appear on pages. Otherwise, firefox operates just normally. Can view text and photos that aren't covered by the black rectangles.

NotePad++ is running, but 1 by 1 goes through all files that I have open and prompts:
The file "C:\path\path\path\something.txt" doesn't exist anymore. Keep this file in editor?

It feels like Twi-Light zone. It is as if my system is running off of a non-existent C drive.

## Information

Antivirus reports no suspicious application

Running disk frag or free memory space apps expedites the trigger time down to 10 minutes, instead of usual 1-4 hours.

Disk frag or free memory space software then terminate with a claim that they have been disconnected from the device.

There is no clicking. In fact, the HDD is silent as a feather.

There are no beeps on startup, RAM supposedly seems fine.

My rig is about 3 years old, built from scratch.

## Troubleshoots

I am going to try Safe Mode. I guess I should have tried that before posting. Silly me. I'll get back with results later. It could be buggy software related, and not actually HDD or RAM.

I will try CHKDSK as well, if it will allow me to...

But curious to hear what do you guys think? RAM, HDD, or something else?

Comment: Do not bother with chkdsk. First read the [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) information from your drive.

Comment: This does not sound like a software problem so scanning for a virus is sort of a waste of time

Comment: follow this and share the boot trace: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks to be hardware related due to the symptoms that you specified.

I would first run a Hardware Diagnostic Scan - Depending on the hardware you have, this may be built into your system via the BIOS. If you don't have a built-in diagnostic tool, I would suggest grabbing [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/#axzz3GmhXQZbm) or [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) - I have used both of these in the past and they have worked rather well.

Both of the mentioned above software can be run from a USB if you are unable to get it installed on your PC

If, after this test, everything passes (HDD, RAM, Video, CPU), I would next run a stress-test on the PC. This will push different parts of your PC to the limits and see how long it takes, and where its failing. I would suggest [BurnInTest](http://www.passmark.com/products/bit.htm) for this process. It's a little less clunky then some of the other programs and it gets the job done.

As stated, this program will run through all hardware connected to your motherboard and, hopefully, detect the problem.

Finally, if everything still checks out, and you are still receiving this problem, it looks like your Motherboard may be the culprit of the problem. I would check your board for any "popped" or "blown" capacitors, remove the CPU and check for any fried or damaged pins/connectors coming from both the underside of the CPU and Motherboard socket.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: It was indeed the hard drive. It didn't just have bad sectors, but whole tracks that had gone bad, reportedly.

**Solution:** Bought 2 new hard disks, 1 SATA HDD for raw data copy from old disk, and other an SSD for OS installation. It was time for an upgrade to SSD anyway.

Using Hiren'sBoot CD, I was able to recover about 99% of what I had. 

Up and running again. Thanks!